# Vim does not see single quotes

Tags: gvim, macvim

I want to use Vim (MacVim) to remove all single quotes from a file. I tried the following:

`:%s/'//g`

`:%s/\'//g`

but in both cases, Vim returns:

`E486: Pattern not found:`

I get the same error when I simply try to search for single quotes:

`/'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the character is not actually a `'` but something that looks like it? You can check with the `ga` command (should print `39`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with @Martin I believe your file doesn't contain single quote but something that looks like single quote.

To look for it you could either

- Copy the single character `yl` and search for it: <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Discover it's code using the `ga` command an search for it: <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>`u2019`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Assuming `2019` is the Unicode code of your looklike quote.

The character `u2019` is actually very similar to single quote `u0027`.

Comment: Yep, it was the character u2019!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)